# Leaflet - Zoom based on mouse scroll and not fixed levels

Tags: javascript, scroll, leaflet, mouseevent

I've been trying different tactics with `leaflet` map to zoom ignoring the default fixed zooming steps of the library, but without any luck so far. Through the following function:

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    if (!e) e = event;
    var direction = (e.detail<0 || e.wheelDelta>0) ? 1 : -1;
}, 
false);
```

I would like to achieve a smooth zooming effect like the one in `Google Maps`, which tracks the zoom based on `deltaY` and mouse scroll event. Do you know how to solve this issue or do you know a reference I could look at?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`zoomSnap` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-zoomsnap) of the map to zero. See also the [`wheelPxPerZoomLevel` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-wheelpxperzoomlevel).

Please note that fractional zoom is a feature introduced in Leaflet 1.0.0. This means that previous versions are not able to use non-integer zoom levels at all.

Comment: Thanks man, that's what I needed. I didn't realised that they have deployed the 1.0.0 version